# Reactjs Function sends data i+1 time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This Code asks the user for confirmation to their audio device.
After a Press on a button, the startRecord() is acitvated and starts the recording. 
stopRecording() stops the recording and once the data is available, the send Function is called and the Blob is sent to the server.

Now the weird part is: After every time the Data is ready, the send Function is called i+1 times.
So after the second time sending to the server, the app is trying to send the blob two times.

The first time works flawlessly.

I can also get it to work when the

```
    stream = navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  });
```

Is being called inside of startRecording(). But then Firefox is asking for permission everytime the User clicks in the button, which isnt good UX as well.

Is there a way to only ask the user once without re-sending the message all the time?
Also weird behaviour is that the listener at "dataavailable" is only fired once (tested with console.log()) but the code from the sending function is being called i+1 times.

I hope someone is able to help

```
export class Speech extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
      isRecording: "false"
     };
   }

  componentDidMount() {
   window.MediaRecorder = require("audio-recorder-polyfill");
     if (!window.MediaRecorder) {
       document.write(decodeURI('%3Cscript 
        src="/polyfill.js">%3C/script>'));
     }
 //I´ve put the navigator.MediaRecorder in the ComponentDidMount, that 
   it only asks the user one time for microphone confirmation.
stream = navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  });
}

recordHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  let myReader = new FileReader();
  if (this.state.isRecording === "false") {
    // Request permissions to record audio
    if (recorder) {
      // Set record to <audio> when recording will be finished
      recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", e => {
        blobby = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
        reader = myReader.readAsText(e.data);

        this.sendMeBaby(e.data);//This is the function that gets 
        called i+1 time after every click (send)


    });
  }
  if (recorder) {
    // Start recording
    recorder.start();
    MessageDisplay.addRecordSign();

    app.updateText();
    console.log("recording started");
    this.startRecording();
    return;
  }
}
if (this.state.isRecording === "true") {
  this.stopRecording();
  return;
}
}

startRecording = () => {
  buttonText = "Recording...";
  this.setState({
    isRecording: "true"
  });
};

stopRecording = () => {
  // Stop recording
  if (recorder) {
    recorder.stop();
    // Remove “recording” icon from browser tab
    recorder.stream.getTracks().forEach(i => i.stop());
  }
  buttonText = "Record";
  this.setState({
    isRecording: "false"
  });
};

sendFunctionWithAjaxCall(){
  sampleCode()
}

render() {
  return (
     <Button
       variant="contained"
       color="secondary"

       onClick={e => {
         this.recordHandler(e);
       }}
     >
       {buttonText}
     </Button>
 );
```

}

Comment: Try to add event listener with `once: true` option to ensure it is called once: `addEventListener('event', callback, {once: true})`. As if the method which is called twice only called in event listener - then the event listener invoked twice. Console groups same output, so there is probably was two invocations.

Comment: Hey thanks for the new insight. This kinda does what it should do.
Only problem is that the voice recording delivers faulty (unusable) data afterwards. But that may be another problem

Comment: So before it was usable data? And was it sending two same data or first was unusable as with `once` approach?

Comment: Check also MDN Documentation on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable. Looks like it should be called multiple times.

Comment: I see now. The only way to make tis work seems to be to let the app listen all the time.
With a press on record one could start a timeslice to record and cut the slice with a stop() method.

Thank you for the help and in understanding the media API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Documentation of [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable) `dataavailable` event is intended to be called multiple times, this can be used to slice recording with a certain interval to have data chunked with smaller pieces.

I assume it should be initialized once, and then on click only start a new recording, this will also fix FF issue (it will ask for permissions once on the page load). So with `stop` the event will be called which will allow you to save the recorder part (between `start` and `stop` calls).

Comment: Yeah thats what I tried immediatly. 
But it does work, when one looks at the Demo: http://mdn.github.io/web-dictaphone/

He clearly got it to work. SO there is a way.
Maybe the concentration is lacking. Tomorrow is another day

I´ll give up for today.
Really appreciate your help!